# breezejs SubQuery one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, angularjs, breeze

I am using AngularJS/Breeze and I need to write the (http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples) following SQL using Breeze format:

SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE ID IN (SELECT contact_id from pharmacy_contact where pharmacy_id='11855'.

My model classes are as follows:

```
[Table("pharmacy_contact")]
public class PharmacyContact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PharmacyId { get; set; }
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }

}

[Table("contact")]
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Extn { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Daytime { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Method { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Type { get; set; }

}
```

Please let me know how I should write the above query in breeze

Answer (score 2):

You may want to rephrase your SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACT inner join pharmacy_contact  on ID = contact_id where pharmacy_id=11855.
```

You can achieve that in breeze:

```
 var query = EntityQuery.from('CONTACTS')
    .expand('pharmacy_contacts')
    .where('pharmacy_contacts','any','pharmacy_id', '==', 11855);
```

Given that you modify the `contact` class to include its pharmacy_contacts:

```
  [Table("contact")]
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Extn { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Daytime { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Method { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Type { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<pharmacy_contact> pharmacy_contacts { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT**

Also the `pharmacy_contact` class to include the navigation back to Contact

```
[Table("pharmacy_contact")]
public class PharmacyContact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PharmacyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
    public contact contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented as suggested above but I am getting an error as:
"unable to locate property: pharmacy_Contact on entityType: Contact:#AIE.Model Query failed". I tried following camelcasing convention which Angular/Breeze follows but none has worked so far. Please,let me know how I should procedd on this.

Comment: That's because you need to tell EF about the FK.. In the `pharmacy_contact` class, add the annotation `[ForeignKey("Contact")]` right before `ContactId ` property

Comment: After adding FK as mentioned above, I am getting following error:
{"The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ContactId' on type 'AIE.Model.Pharmacy_Contact' is not valid. The navigation property 'contact' was not found on the dependent type 'AIE.Model.Pharmacy_Contact'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name."}

Comment: I have edited my answer and included the `contact` class